# vnc doesn't work (connection successful, but I can't see any graphics)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, vnc

I'm trying to use VNC on a remote server of mine. My local machine and the remote machine are both running Ubuntu 18.04. There are no errors produced by any of the installation commands, but I just can't get anything graphical to appear.

Here are the steps I followed. On my remote machine inside a terminal after connecting with ssh:

```
sudo apt install -y xvfb
sudo apt install -y x11vnc
sudo touch /var/log/x11vnc.log
sudo chmod a+rw /var/log/x11vnc.log
/usr/bin/x11vnc -ncache 10 -ncache_cr -viewpasswd remote_view_only_pass -passwd some_pass123  -display :0 -forever -shared -logappend /var/log/x11vnc.log -bg -noipv6
```

I think all of these are working, however, I am not able to connect to this server and see graphical output on my local machine.The VNC client I am using is `vinagre`. I think most of the other ones are paid or only work on Windows/Mac (do I even need a 3rd party app, though?).

I open vinagre up, click connect, select `ssh` as the protocol, type in my ip address into the host space, enter my username, and hit connect. In the window, it looks like a regular terminal session, it prompts me for my password, I enter it, and this looks exactly like it usually does when I ssh in **without** graphics. I also try to enter the following into the terminal-looking vinagre window:

```
sudo apt install -y x11-apps
DISPLAY=:0 xeyes &
```

but nothing graphical pops up.

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial I was following didn't mention that I had to set up a tunnel on my local machine:

```
ssh -L 5900:127.0.0.1:5900 -N root@1.2.3.4
```

which assumes my remote machine's ip is 1.2.3.4 and the username is `root`. Leave that running and then in another terminal on your local machine type 
`vncviewer localhost:5900`
and use one of those two passwords in that command above, either `remote_view_only_pass` or `some_pass123`.